# Putting array as arguments to Laravel's factory that is repeated

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, factory

```
$categoryTitles = [
  'Games',
  'Running',
  'Hacking',
  'Walking',
];

$categoryDescriptions = [
  'this is nice',
  'kinda cool',
  'really good',
  'fine',
];

$categories = factory(App\Category::class, 4)->create([
  'title' => array_pop($categoryTitles),
  'description' => array_pop($categoryDescriptions),
]);
```

By looking at above code you probably will know what I am trying to do.

I wanna run 4 times factory with custom items defined in arrays.

But it doesn't work, because it takes last items from both arrays and is working on them 4 times. It doesn't take next and next until the array is empty.

I don't know exactly how to acomplish this. I think code explains what I wanna do.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to call factory's `create()` method 4 times:

```
$categories = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; ++$i) {
  $categories[] = factory(App\Category::class)->create([
    'title' => $categoryTitles[$i],
    'description' => $categoryDescriptions[$i],
  ]);
}
```

Comment: There is no other way?
Especially Laravel's way?

Comment: There's lots of other ways, this one is in my opionion the simplest and most readable one. create() method requires you to pass an array of attributes you want to overwrite in the default factory definition. If you want to create 4 different objects you need to pass 4 different data sets but create() only allows you to pass a single data set - that's why you simply have to call it 4 times.

Answer (score 0):

jedrzej.kurylo is right. You could take advantage of [Laravel Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections) and do something like this:

```
$categories = collect([
    ['title' => 'Games',   'description' => 'this is nice'],
    ['title' => 'Running', 'description' => 'kinda cool'],
    ['title' => 'Hacking', 'description' => 'really good'],
    ['title' => 'Walking', 'description' => 'fine'],
])->mapWithKeys(function ($category) {
    return factory(App\Category::class)->create([
        'title' => $category['title'],
        'description' => $category['description']
    ]);
});
```